# How to get EC2 memory utilization using command line (aws cli)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying to get EC2 memory utilization using aws cli and I see that `EC2MemoryUtilization` is not available as a metric. I installed cloudwatch agent in the ec2 instance and I have created a dashboard for `mem_used_percent`.

Now I want to consume the memory used data points programmatically. I could find for `CPUUtilization` but I am unable to find anything for Memory utilization.

Any help in this regard is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Memory utilization is not collected by cloudwatch since it has to be pushed from the instance. By default cloudwatch collects data that are available at the hypervisor level and memory utilization is not available at the hypervisor. You have to push a custom metric for memory and then use the CLI to query it.

Answer (score 0):

This python script pushes the system memory metrics to cloudwatch in a custom namespace. Schedule the script in crontab to execute it at every 1 minute or 5 minutes to plot the system memory metrics with respect to time. Ensure that IAM role assigned to the vm has sufficient privileges to put metric data to cloudwatch.

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python
import psutil
import requests
import json
import os
import boto3

get_memory = psutil.virtual_memory()
free_memory = get_memory.free/(1024*1024*1024)
print "Free Memory: ", free_memory, "GB"


headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
req = requests.get(url='http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/cloudwatch_access', headers=headers)
res = json.loads(req.text)

AccessKeyId = res['AccessKeyId']
SecretAccessKey = res['SecretAccessKey']
Token = res['Token']
Region = "ap-south-1"

os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = AccessKeyId
os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = SecretAccessKey
os.environ["AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"] = Token
os.environ["AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"] = Region

namespace = 'mynamespace'
dimension_name = 'my_dimension_name'
dimension_value = 'my_dimension_value'

cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
cloudwatch.put_metric_data(
  MetricData=[
    {
      'MetricName': 'Free Memory',
      'Dimensions': [
        {
          'Name': dimension_name,
          'Value': dimension_value
        },
      ],
      'Unit': 'Gigabytes',
      'Value': free_memory
    },
  ],
  Namespace=namespace
)
```

Comment: Cloudwatch agent is not needed here. It is implemented in production environment and there was no load impact on the system because of this cron job.